# Trying to convert windows exe for chrome extension to dot net core 2

Tags: google-chrome-extension, .net-core, chrome-native-messaging

I have heard that Dot net core only generates dll file and the only way to run them is using the command

```
dotnet myapp.dll
```

I have a chrome extension and i am trying to do some operations . For example, on chrome extension i enter two numbers and then click send button. this triggers the native messaging and a windows executable/dll is called which takes these 2 numbers as stdin and returns the sum as stdout which would be displayed on chrome extension .

Earlier it was an exe file which was working fine. Now i have migrated the code to dotnet core 2.0 . My unit tests work fine but the dll is unable to execute . i dont see any logs as well . my best guess is that the dll is not getting called at all. somehow i have no idea how to check if the app is getting called from chrome extension

```
 {
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "myapp",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myapp.dll",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://lpfjfcebobk**************/"
  ]
}
```

UPDATE -1

I was able to solve this by creating a bat file which in turn calls the dll file by the following command

```
dotnet my_app.dll
```

Also my bat file looks like this

```
 @echo off
:: Copyright (c) 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
:: Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
:: found in the LICENSE file.

dotnet "my_app.dll" %*
```

and my app_manifest looks like this

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "description": "myapp",
  "path": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\myapp.bat",
  "type": "stdio",
  "allowed_origins": [
    "chrome-extension://lpfjfcebobk**************/"
  ]
}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm updated problem statement
and yes the chrome extension is registered , app manifest is updated.

Comment: @wOxxOm updated manifest

Comment: DLLs cannot be executed directly so I guess you need to make a simple `.bat` script that runs dotnet myapp.dll

Comment: so when i replace myapp.dll with myapp.exe (not dot net core) ... everything works fine

Comment: By that i just meant that manifest file is correct . i was assuming dll's will be autoexecute from the runtime environment.Let me try the bat file once.

Comment: thanks @wOxxOm for your help . finally was able to solve this.

Comment: @mobman Could you please post your solution as an answer and remove it from the question part?

Comment: @Xan : my account is blocked for some reason ... can post an answer.

Comment: @Xan please upvote my effort if you feel i have given my findings back to the community so that i have enough karma to answer